# Change the title text of JMenuItem upon click?

Tags: java, swing, onclick, title, jmenuitem

I am adding a `JMenuItem` (Show History) that will toggle the appearance of a `JPanel` upon click. But after doing so, I want to change the title of that menu item to state the opposite action (Hide History). Is there a way to change just the text for that menu item, or must I remove the old `JMenuItem` and add a new one?

```
JMenuItem history = new JMenuItem("Show History");
history.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        //code here to show the history
        //history.changeText("Hide History") OR viewMenu.remove(history) and create/add new one
    }
});
viewMenu.add(history);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is what you do:

```
history.setText("Hide History");
```

And make history `final`.

Comment: There is no need to make the "history" variable final. You get the menu item from the `ActionEvent` by using the `getSource()` method.